# Setting the value of properties in PHP

Tags: php, oop, properties

I have a class called members, i have an example below. What i am asking is how do i set the values of title. So for example , i only allow Mr, Mrs, Miss and any other values will `throw out an error` stating `Only Mr,Mrs,Miss is allowed` , Firstname must be John..

```
class Member 
{

    private $title;
    private $firstname;

    public function __construct( $title ) 
    {
        $this->title = $title;

    }

    public function showProfile() 
    {
        echo "<dl>";
        echo "<dt>Title:</dt><dd>$this->title</dd>";
        echo "</dl>";
    }
}

$data = new Member( "Mrr" );
$data->showProfile();
```

Comment: do you want this as an exception or as a string that you can return to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this , hope this will be helpful.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/803351)

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

class Member
{

    private $title;

    public function __construct($title)
    {
        if(!in_array($title, ["Mr","Mrs","Miss"]))
        {
            throw new Exception("Only Mr,Mrs,Miss are allowed!");
            //or you can simple echo out your message instead of exception
        }
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function showProfile()
    {
        echo "<dl>";
        echo "<dt>Title:</dt><dd>$this->title</dd>";
        echo "</dl>";
    }

}

$data = new Member("Mrr");
```

Optionally you can set a variable for this `error` with `in the class`, which prevent further execution of methods of class script. You can also do it like this

**Solution 2:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/803352)

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

class Member
{

    private $title;
    private $error=false;
    public function __construct($title)
    {
        if(!in_array($title, ["Mr","Mrs","Miss"]))
        {
            $this->error=true;
        }
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function showProfile()
    {
        if($this->error!==true)
        {
            echo "<dl>";
            echo "<dt>Title:</dt><dd>$this->title</dd>";
            echo "</dl>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Only Mr,Mrs,Miss is allowed!";
        }
    }

}

$data = new Member("Mrr");
$data->showProfile();
```

Comment: thanks , also thanks for the intro to Eval , i am going to use this alot !

Comment: sorry could you add if there were to fields so lets say title and firstname has to be James for example, i am trying to add it and it only shows one exception at a time

Comment: @ALCHI Sorry i didnt get that, Can you please explain?

Comment: i added a new property called firstname to my question , so now it has to properties to validate . Title must be Mr,Mrs,Miss and firstname must be John, when i try your first example with one property it works fine, but with two properties it only shows the error for one

Comment: Thank you @Sahil , that is all i need !

Answer (score 1):

Make a setter

```
   function setTitle($newTitle){
      if(in_array($newTitle, array('Mr', 'Miss', 'Mrs' ))
        $this->title=$newTitle;
      else
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
```

And then call it from the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I didnt like any of the answers.
Here's mine. I think you should use a mutator in your solution. The member class should be decoupled from the setter.

```
class Member
{

private $title;

public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}
public function showProfile()
{
    return sprintf("<dl><dt>Title</dt><dt><dd>%s</dd></dt></dl>" , $this->title );
}

}



class TitleProperty
{
protected $name = 'title';
protected $allowed_allowed = ['mr', 'mrs', 'miss'];

public $errors = [];

/**
*@param Member $member
*@param string $value
*/
public function __construct( Member $member, $value )
{
    if(!in_array($value, $this->allowed_allowed )){
        $this->errors[] = "Only Mr,Mrs,Miss is allowed";
    }
    else{
        $member->setTitle( $value );
    }
}
}

$member = new Member();
$property = new TitleProperty($member, 'hello');
if($property->errors){
print_r($property->errors);
}
else{
echo 'title set.';
}
```

There you go